# How to use has_scope with inherited_resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-scope

I'm following git wiki for `has_scope`.

It has an example:

```
# in model
scope :featured, -> whatever

# in controller
has_scope :by_degree
...
@graduations = apply_scopes(Graduation).all
```

So did that:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :inactive, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
end

class Admin::AccountsController < Admin::BaseController
  has_scope :inactive

  private
  def collection
    apply_scopes(Account)
  end

  def end_of_association_chain
    @end_of_association_chain ||= super.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

When accessing collection in the view (like `collection.each`) - getting this error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x007fbeca533eb0>
```

It seems to give a class. But I expect it to contain an array of objects.

Tried to add the `load` method:

```
collection.load.each ...
```

But got another error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
```

Have no idea where to look further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did this wrong.

```
private
  def collection
    @accounts ||= end_of_association_chain.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
```

And this is all. Inherited_resources apply scopes automatically inside of end_of_association_chain